# How to specify a key for React children when mapping over an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, key

I have a method in a react Contact List component where I am returning another component. I have got it working but am curious if there is a better way to structure how I am using the key.

Specifically - I'm asking about this line of code from the method below (data is hard coded as sample to get started):

```
return <ShortContact contact={contact} key={contact.id}/>
```

Here is the code in context:

```
_getContacts() {
    let contactList = [
        {
            id: 1,
            fName: "aaa",
            lName: "aaaaa",
            imgUrl: "http://brainstorminonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/blah.jpg",
            email: "aaa@aaaa.com",
            phone: "999999999999"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            fName: "bbbbb",
            lName: "bbbbbbb",
            imgUrl: "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/bbb.jpg",
            email: "bbb@bbb-bbb.com",
            phone: "888888888888"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            fName: "Number",
            lName: "Three",
            imgUrl: "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-iYgp2G1mD4o/TssPyGjJ4bI/AAAAAAAAGl0/UoweTTF1-3U/s1600/Number+3+Coloring+Pages+14.gif",
            email: "three@ccccc.com",
            phone: "333-333-3333"
        }
    ];

    return contactList.map((contact) => {
        "use strict";
        return <ShortContact contact={contact} key={contact.id}/>
    });
}
```

ShortContact Component Render:

```
class ShortContact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <li className="contact-short well whiteBG">
                    <img  className="contact-short-thumb" src={this.props.contact.imgUrl}/>
                    <p className="contact-short-name">{this.props.contact.fName}</p><br />
                    <p className="contact-short-email">{this.props.contact.email}</p>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I struggled with how to make it work and not get the warning `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` However I am wondering if the syntax or structure is valid and if it should be refactored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code. The key is required so that react knows how to render the children nodes. In fact your implementation is exactly what react requires the programmer to do. Now the details of which key to use and such can be changed, but it looks like you have the most performant solution already.

The main requirement is that the key is unique so as long as contact.id is always unique (which if its coming from a database then it will be) then you are fine.

Alternatively you can use an index on your map for the key but I wouldn't really recommend it (i'll explain below after the code snippet).

```
contactList.map((contact, i) => {
    return <ShortContact contact={contact} key={i}/>
});
```

Personally I think your approach is the best approach because it can prevent additional renders. What I mean is for instance when a new contact is returned from the server every contact row would be re-rendered because the index in the array for each contact is different (assuming you aren't treating it like a stack)... The different index with new contact data at that index would cause the re-render. Because contact.id is a static number if the data for that contact hasn't changed then react wont re-render it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm very new to React - and sometimes hearing the reasons as related to the code I'm actually writing makes a big difference.

Comment: @MaryCamacho you are very welcome! you had the right approach and that is exactly how react is intended to be used! :) good job. If you have any more questions or want to understand more feel free to ask and I'll try and explain the best I can :)

Comment: Thanks! - I actually do have another question - because in order to add a create contact form on the same page - I needed to move my data up a level to the parent component... Here is the new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991994/move-method-from-one-component-to-another-in-react-and-still-be-able-to-use-in-o

Comment: You should not use the index for the key value.

Comment: @joetidee isn't that what I say in my post? Technically you can it is an alternative, but I say it's not recommended.

Comment: It's not clear why you shouldn't use index from your description.

Comment: @JoeTidee sorry, I thought it was pretty clear. What about it is not clear? I say that using the id instead of an index will prevent additional renders. that an array index position change for items will cause them to be re-rendered when the key is the array index. If you want to edit the post to be more descriptive about what you think isn't clear feel free to :)

Answer (score 0):

The use of a unique key is required. In your example, using the id is ideal. see the following for more information:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html