# Why can I not map keys onto React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my render looks like this:

```
<ul>{liElements}</ul>
```

the `liElements` is an array of `<li>word</li>` created with a for-of loop.

(for the sake of argument, I do not have access to the function that creates that array)

I'm understanding the value of keys, however they are not valuable in this situation as none of the component's values will be changing, Especially since in absence of a key, "react takes the array position as key" anyway, Perfect! I want that, why  does it insist on sending me a error message letting me know they are necessary, I know it doesn't know they're not necessary, be it also doesn't know they are necessary, so how bout a yellow warning?

I know I can ignore it, but it is very annoying to always have the message log to console, (especially since this message could useful elsewhere)

```
react.js:19287 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
```

So since I can do

```
liElements[0].key // null
```

I thought I can just do

```
liElements.map(function(a,i){a.key=i;});
<ul>{liElements}</ul>
```

alas;

```
bundle.js:39123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'key' of object '#<Object>'
```

Why is it readOnly? Is there anyway I can assign these totally unnecessary keys after I receive the array just so the error message stops showing?

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but I would assume its because of your negative tone in the question. You will most likely get more downvotes if you leave the question as is. We should always try to keep SO clear of negativity and we should try to keep things professional so that other passers by can have a clear question and solution when they have the same issue :) just my 2 cents on the matter though.

Comment: Thanks, John, also "So React is by far the most annoying error messaging framework", not react is the most annoying I think it's got huge potential. Ill clean up the question.

Comment: no problem! glad I could help. If my answer solves your issue I'd greatly appreciate it if you mark it as accepted so this question can be closed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say you have a list of items you want to be li's

```
let items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5']

let elems = items.map( (item, index) => { return <li key={index}>{item}</li> }
```

You want to map your list and as you do specify a key. Why do this? because you are rendering a tree into the DOM and for React to know which exact element you are going to try and manipulate you need to pass a specific key. This way you can do things like `onClick` handlers.. and stuff like that. 
Additionallly React uses these specific keys for performance in rendering. so even if you think its unnecessary and the end result is identical when not passing a key. It still is REALLY important, because React wont have to generate a key for every item every single render.

Finally when you go to render it.

```
return (
    <ul>
        {elems}
    </ul>
)
```

#### Edit

To what Dave was saying in the comments.. Keys are created on object creation aka `React.createElement(...)`. After their creation they are immutable. Again this is because you are creating a tree.. if you try to manually change a key then the whole tree structure would have to be 're-keyd' which is a bad idea (this is why it is read only). The key is an internal thing that react uses, but when you render dynamic elements you need to specify the key so there is no duplication of keys.

#### Edit 2

Heres some helpful links for you

[Another Answer I Gave Regarding Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36974428/2733506) 
[React Dynamic Children Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) 
[Importance of Keys - Example](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/)
[Dynamic elements with examples of wrong ways to do it](http://revelry.co/dynamic-child-components-with-react/)

Comment: I think the OPs objection was that they explicitly *won't* be manipulated. It was stated childishly, and s/he wasn't solving it properly, but it's a valid issue

Comment: @DaveNewton Agreed the question was written in frustration, I'm not sure I agree its a valid issue though. No one should want or expect magic to happen under the hood. writing out exactly what you want everything to be all the time is the way to go anyways. React has no idea that these wont be manipulated (and it shouldn't), and if they aren't going to be why not just write out the elements instead of trying to make them in a for loop?

Comment: Agreed re: being explicit. My point was that is a valid question about React and element keys, which is documented, but not necessarily intuitive when you know (or at least believe) keys shouldn't be necessary :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Ah gotcha! Yea the first time I got that warning I had to do a google search to figure it out :)

Comment: This is a good, complete answer, with immediately-actionable information, and followup discussion. There's no way this should be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set keys, I believe you have to set them in the li elements themselves like this:

```
<li key={index}>list item</li>
```